# PHP 7 FPM - OPcache file cache vs memory cache performance

Tags: php, performance, php-7, fpm, opcache

I've been using OPcache with php-fpm 7 a while now and works fine.

I've been wondering what's the impact performance wise with `opcache.file_cache` and `opcache.file_cache_only` options enabled.

Are there any benchmarks?
Have anyone tried it on production?

My other settings:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=192
opcache.revalidate_freq=180
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=12
opcache.max_accelerated_files=6000
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Best Regards